# Jade include produces error when trying to include a file in parent folder sibling

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug

So I have this piece of Jade code in the top of my layout.jade file:

```
doctype html
  html
    head
      include ./../jade/includes/head
```

This produces the error

> ENOENT, no such file or directory '[project
>   root]/jade/jade/includes/head.jade'

Notice the double instance of 'jade'.

The folder structure is like this:

```
[project home]
  app/
    jade/
      layouts/
        layout.jade
      includes/
        head.jade
```

BTW, this produces the same error:

```
include ../jade/includes/head
```

This is a fairly standard [WSK](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/starter-kit/) project (which uses Gulp), compiling the Jade using [gulp-accord](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-accord). See snippet from gulp file below:

```
// Compile Jade files.
gulp.task('jade', function () {

  return gulp.src('app/jade/**/*.jade')
    .pipe($.accord('jade', { pretty: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});
```

I got around the problem by specifying a 'basedir' ("app/") as an option for gulp-accord in the gulpfile and using this instead:

```
include /jade/includes/head
```

Perhaps that is simply better practice, but I would still like to know why the error occurred.

EDIT:

Having banged my head against this for a while I missed including a very important part, which is this:

```
include ./../includes/head
```

And that it throws the error:

> ENOENT, no such file or directory '[project home]/app/includes/head.jade

So it's damned if you do, damned if you don't...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a jade file at `[project home]/app/jade/layout.jade` or something that didn't get cleaned up? Maybe it got copied instead of moved into the `layouts` folder?

Comment: You should probably change your gulp task to only take in files from `app/jade/layouts/*.jade` as well. No reason to to compile anything else, right?

Comment: Well, the layouts are not what turns into actual html pages, they are used by for example app/jade/jade-test.jade like so:
`extends /jade/layouts/article-layout.jade` to get jade-test.html in the served root (.tmp or dist).

Comment: Your comment got me thinking, though. It seems the problem is that the layout file gets compiled twice; once on it's own and once as part of the jade file extending it. `include` seems to paste the code right in and then resolve any extends (and probably includes), meaning we have different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of further testing, the problem lies in that the layout was rendered both on its own and when used by way of `extends` in other files. The proof is in that the errors are thrown for the different files depending on the path: One for the `jade/jade/`, the other for when backing out one step to far as brought up in the edit.

The paths to other files in the structure needs to survive both these contexts, i.e. by using absolute paths (like `include /jade/includes/head`) with a `basedir` option set in the gulpfile (value of "app", in my particular WSK case). Or you need to make sure that partials and layouts do not get compiled by excluding them from the `gulp.src()`. In the case of my folder structure that would be this:

```
gulp.task('jade', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/jade/**/*.jade', 
                   '!app/jade/layouts{,/**}', 
                   '!app/jade/includes{,/**}'])
    .pipe($.accord('jade', { pretty: true, basedir: "app" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Using a `basedir` and absolute path you do not have to worry about adding further folders in the future. But you probably do not want to compile layouts and partials to HTML anyway, so why not do both?

A good walkthrough on excluding is [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/165).

Answer (score 0):

Your included path will be relative to the directory `/app/jade/layouts` of current file - `layout.jade`.  That is why you need to traverse up the directory tree (`../`) only once to end up in `/app/jade` directory. From here you were trying to get into jade directory again (`jade/`), which was not present (`/app/jade/jade` does not exist). Instead go straight to `includes/head`.

The include code below should work properly:

```
include ./../includes/head
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have put that example in as well, because that somehow gives me the error "ENOENT, no such file or directory '[project home]/app/includes/head.jade". That is what is making the double showing of 'jade' even more confusing. Making an edit.

Comment: Could you please post your gulpfile jade compiling fragment?

Comment: As requested; check the question for the code fragment.

Comment: My current theory is that the problem arises with or without the `jade/` because the layout.jade file is compiled twice; once as part of the file extending it, and once on its own.